# Filtering through a list of Words (Python)

Tags: python, function, text, python-2.7

I am trying to do something like this with Python.

Suppose my word list is:

```
is, are, was, the, he, she, fox, jumped
```

And my text is like `He was walking down the road.`.

I want to create a function which will return

```
['He', ' ', 'was', ' ', 'w','a','l','k','i','n','g', ' ', 'd','o','w','n',' ', 'the', 'r','o','a','d','.']
```

That it is it will return a list in which every letter is an element but words in the wordlist are taken as one element.

Somebody, please help me with creating this function

Comment: Have You tried something already? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = ['is', 'are', 'was', 'the', 'he', 'she', 'fox', 'jumped']
s = "He was walking down the road."
new = []
for word in phrase.split(): 
    if word.lower() in filters:
            new.append(word)
    else:
            new.extend(word)
    new.append(' ')

print new[:-1] # We slice the last element because it is ' '.
```

Prints:

```
['He', ' ', 'was', ' ', 'w', 'a', 'l', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'w', 'n', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'r', 'o', 'a', 'd', '.']
```

As a function:

```
def filter_down(phrase, filters):
    new = []
    for word in phrase.split(): 
        if word.lower() in filters:
                new.append(word)
        else:
                new.extend(list(word)) # list(word) is ['w', 'a', 'l', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
        new.append(' ')
    return new
```

Comment: The `list` call can be omitted: `new.extend(word)`.

Comment: +1 Another way to do it: `new.extend([word] if word.lower() in filters else word)`.

Comment: @FMc A possibility indeed, but perhaps the current solution is neater? It's nice though :)

Comment: What do I do in order to get something like `['walk','i','n','g']` to the function when the text passed is `'walking'` but the filter contains only `['walk']`.

Please help

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Good question; no idea! I've tried some stuff, but that may need a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

My first python code, hope it works for you.

```
array = ["is", "are", "was", "the", "he", "she", "fox", "jumped"]
sentence = "He was walking down the road"
words = sentence.split(" ");
newarray = [];
for word in words:
    if word.lower() in array:
         newarray.append(word)
    for i in range(0, len(word), 1):
         newarray.append(word[i:i+1])
    newarray.append(" ")

for word in newarray:
     print word
```